# Java compiles with no errors, runs first line, then doesn't continue or end

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I am working on a project for my intro to java class and I can't get it to continue. The first part of the project is supposed to use a method to read a file and turn it into an array, then retrieve that array in the main method. It compiled with no errors, but when I run it, it prompts the user for the file name and when you type it and press enter it just sits there. It does not end the program but it also doesn't continue. Am I doing something wrong?

Here is the method that reads the file and creates the array:

```
   public static int[] inputData() throws IOException
   {
      Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Enter input filename: ");
      String fileName = kb.nextLine();
      File file = new File(fileName);
      if(!file.exists())
      {
         System.out.println("File not found.");
         System.exit(0);
      }
      Scanner inFile = new Scanner(file);

      int size = 0;
      while(inFile.hasNext())
      {
         size++;
      }

      int[] array = new int[size];
      while(inFile.hasNext())
      {
         for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
         {
            array[i] = inFile.nextInt();
         }
      }
      inFile.close();
      return array;
   }
```

and here is the main method:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
   {
      int[] array = inputData();
      int length = array.length;
      System.out.println("Original array: ");
      printArray(array, length);
      System.out.println();

      System.out.print("The first element out of order is at index "
                       + outOfOrder(array));
      System.out.println(".");

      System.out.println("Reversed array: ");
      reverseArray(array);

      System.out.println("Sorted array in descending order: ");
      selectionSort(array);

      System.out.println("Delete repeats: ");
      deleteRepeats(array);
   }
```

I am very new to java so I apologize if this is an obvious error. Please help, thank you!

Comment: `while(inFile.hasNext()) { size++; }` will probably loop infinitely, because `hasNext()` does not consume the next token, only returns whether there's one available.

Answer (score 1):

Loop in your code will never complete as you are not using inFile.next() inside the loop.

```
while(inFile.hasNext()){
    size++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the two while cycles and add this:

```
        int[] array = new int[1];
        int index= 0;
        while (inFile.hasNext()) {
            array[index] = inFile.nextInt();
            if(inFile.hasNext()) {
                index++;
                int[] array2 = new int[array.length + 1];
                for (int i = 0; i<array.length;i++) {
                    array2[i] = array[i];
                }
                array = array2;
            }
        }
```

This code will increase the size of array[] for each next element.